# In python, does lock get automatically released when an exception happens?

Tags: python, locking

for example:

```
import threading

lock = threading.Lock()

with lock:
    some code that throws an exception
```

This is assuming that code that throws an exception isn't wrapped in a try except block.

Comment: Generally yes, if an exception occurs, the locks will be released.

Comment: Yes if you use `with lock: ...`, otherwise no.

Comment: Just made a small program to confirm this. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The whole point of using your lock as a context manager (`with lock:`) is for Python to notify that lock object when an exception occurs.

So yes, the lock will unlock itself when an exception occurs because the `with` statement ensures it is notified of an exception.